# Ask for iOS permissions once in a while if they still denied

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, permissions, ios-permissions

In my iOS app I have some things that need permissions from user. 
For example : permissions to receive push-notifications.

I want to ask such users for enabling permissions once in a while until they will approve it. I don't want to ask each time user launches app.

I have function that opens app settings where user can enable notification

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func openAppSettings() {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about storing the date of last permission request and each time the app launches - check how many days ago user was asked for permissions last time. I don't know why but it seems not elegant for me.

Could you please suggest more elegant way to solve it?

Comment: starting from iOS7 but it will be ok even if there is solution from iOS8

Comment: I may use number of times app opened, everytime user opens the app I increment `Int` in `UserDefaults`. Once user open app on nth time(ex. 7th time) I show popup.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant ways:

- ask for permission again right after user has made an (in-app) purchase, arguing you want to alert for future offers
- ask for permission again right after user has made a (remote) subscription/reservation, arguing you want to alert for the event/booking/delivery status
- ask for permission again right after user has triggered an (in-game) action that will take more than 1 hour to be accomplished, arguing you want to alert for completion-status

If your app does not provide services for purchasing anything, does not trigger anything with real-life impact, and does not have long gaming sessions, then it may reveal that you have no meaningful trigger for those notifications.

Comment: I mostly agree with you point but there are cases when business asks for more push-notifications subscribers among current app users

Comment: @moonvader you may clarify in your question what kind of business model have your app (in-app?, governmental funding?, advertising?) and what is the content of those notifications ("happy birthday!", "Your delivery is ready", "The president blocked you", "Get discount on Viagra!", "You got mail!", "Buy 1 dragon, get 1 egg free", etc.)